# RxJava Android onError takes too long to be called

Tags: android, rx-java

I'm using `RxJava` on my Android app and I have a problem with `onError`.

I'm doing this:

```
operationalLayer.operationalConfig(new OperationalRequest())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.immediate())
    .observeOn(Schedulers.immediate())
    .subscribe(new CustomSubscriber<OperationalResponse>(bundle, null) {
        @Override
        public void onNext(OperationalResponse response) {
          //Do something
            super.onNext(response);
        }
    });
```

At some point, in the `operationalConfig` method I check if the network connection is available and if not I'm returning an error.

```
public Observable<OperationalResponse> operationalConfig(final OperationalRequest operationalRequest) {
    if (!Network.hasInternet()) {
        Log.d("No available internet for operationalConfig");
        return Observable.error(new NoInternetException());
    }

    return Observable.defer....
}
```

Than, in my `CustomSubscriber` I have this:

```
@Override
public void onError(final Throwable e) {
    if (e instanceof NoInternetException) {
        // do something
        Log.d("No internet connection available");
    } 
    // other things
}
```

Looking at the log messages I have a huge delay since it's detected that there is no internet connection available and the `onError` method is called.

```
11-16 12:07:37.378 23779-24183 D/CustomTag: OperationalLayer No available internet for operationalConfig
11-16 12:07:57.459 23779-24416 D/CustomTag: CustomSubscriber No internet connection available
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Could you remove observeOn and use Schedulers.io() for subscribeOn and validate the result again?

Comment: @HansWurst Tried but I believe it is taking even more time. Roughly from 20 seconds to almost 2 minutes

Comment: Hmm, I dont see something broken here. Would need more code to help debug. Actually, wrapp everything in operationalConfig into Observable.defer in order not to block on subscription. The onNext on subscription will happen on given scheduler, but the entering and checking if network is available would happen on current thread.

Comment: Nope. Same thing. Do not have many more code :(

Comment: Could you post the project on github or whatever and I will step through the code and look for the error.

Comment: @HansWurst Found the problem. See my answer please. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

Did not posted here the code because did not think it was relevant. In fact It was.

Between `operationalLayer.operationalConfig` and the method itself I had this:

```
@Override
    public Observable<OerationalResponse> operationalConfig(OperationRequest operationalRequest) {
        //Something
        return network.opcoConfigs(opcoConfigRequest)
                .retryWhen(//Something);
    }
```

Inside the `Func` that I pass to `retryWhen` I now handle the error properly so that if no network connection, the retry mechanism is stopped immediately and the `InternetException` is returned to the subscriber.

Comment: I have the similar problem but I couldn't solve it with your explanation. could you please take a look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202300/retrofit-rxjava-takes-long-time-to-invoke-onerror-when-server-connection-faile/46213362#46213362