# Retrofit + Rxjava takes long time to invoke onError when server connection failed

Tags: android, networking, retrofit, rx-java, connectivity

I'm using Retrofit + Rxjava to get a list of entities from server, by my design when the task fails, first it checks Internet connection and after that it checks the connection to the server in `doOnError` method of `Observable`.

When Client is not connected to the Internet `doOnError` is invoked in a reasonable time and user get the error message but the problem is when Internet is connected and I get wrong port or domain (to check the server problem error) It takes a long time (about 1 min or longer) and it's really annoying.
How can I reduce this time and what's the reason?

#### how I check Internet and Server connection :

```java
public static boolean checkConnection(String ipOrUrl, int port) {
    try {
        int timeoutMs = 100;
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        SocketAddress soketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(ipOrUrl, port);
        socket.connect(soketAddress, timeoutMs);
        socket.close();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

#### how I try to get list of entities :

```java
    foodgetRetorfitService.getRestaurants()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
//here I'm checking the internet and server connection in the onlineTask if retrofit fail
//and if clients get Online this ( getRestaurantFromServer ) is called again.
            .doOnError(error -> {
                error.printStackTrace();
                NetworkUtils.doOnlineTask(new OnlineTask() {
                    public void doWhenOnline() {
                        getResturantsFromServer();
                    }
                }, true);
            })
            .subscribe(new Observer<List<Restaurant>>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(List<Restaurant> restaurants) {
                    restaurantItemAdapter.updateAdapterData(restaurants);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onError: rxjava and retrofit error : can't get restaurant list");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
```

#### how `doOnlineTask` is Implemented

```java
    public static void doOnlineTask(OnlineTask onlineTask, boolean autoRetry, int retryTimeout) {
        NetworkUtils.isOnline(autoRetry)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnError(error -> {
//here I check the Exception type ( I raised them when checking the connection )
                    if (error instanceof InternetConnectionException)
                        onlineTask.doWhenInternetFaild();

                    if (error instanceof ServerConnectionException)
                        onlineTask.doWhenServerFaild();
                })
                .retryWhen(t -> t.delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                .subscribe(result -> {
                            if (result.equals(NetworkStatus.CONNECTED))
                                onlineTask.doWhenOnline();
                            else {
                                if (result.equals(NetworkStatus.INTERNET_FAILD))
                                    onlineTask.doWhenInternetFaild();
                                else if (result.equals(NetworkStatus.SERVER_FAILD))
                                    onlineTask.doWhenInternetFaild();
                            }
                        }, error -> error.printStackTrace()
                );
    }
```

#### `onlineTask` is just an abstract class

```java
abstract public void doWhenOnline();

public void doWhenInternetFaild() {
   //implemented somehow
}


public void doWhenServerFaild() {
   //implemented somehow
}
```

#### What I tried :

I guessed it's timeout problem so I changed Retrofit timeout with `OkHttpClient` and It does not worked. also I changed timeouts set by myself and I reduced them. not working.

Comment: I am having the same problem here. Mine is taking 10 seconds to process while there is no Internet but active network. while in aeroplane mode it takes 1 second to process. Did you find the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using OkHttp client to go with Retrofit. What you are looking for is most probably a connection timeout.

You can set different timeouts when building a client.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
```

Comment: I tried this and I changed all the timeouts to 0 (every timeout anywhere for testing purpose) and it still takes about 18 seconds to raise error

Comment: Have you tried to remove a retryWhen function? Other than that I can not help you.

Comment: I tried now and it took 22 seconds to the error, it didn't work. tnx anyway.